# Possible NP-complete problem?

Tags: algorithm, allocation, np-complete, constraint-satisfaction

I'd just like someone to verify whether the following problem is NP-complete or if there is actually a better/easier solution to it than simple brute-force combination checking.

We have a sort-of resource allocation problem in our software, and I'll explain it with an example.

Let's say we need 4 people to be at work during the day-shift. This number, and the fact that it is a "day-shift" is recorded in our database.

However, we don't require just anyone to fill those spots, there's some requirements that needs to be filled in order to fit the bill.

Of those 4, let's say 2 of them has to be a nurse, and 1 of them has to be doctors.

One of the doctors also has to work as part of a particular team.

So we have this set of information:

> Day-shift: 4
>      1 doctor
>      1 doctor, need to work in team A
>      1 nurse

The above is not the problem. The problem comes when we start picking people to work the day-shift and trying to figure out if the people we've picked so far can actually fill the criteria.

For instance, let's say we pick James, John, Ursula and Mary to work, where James and Ursula are doctors, John and Mary are nurses.

Ursula also works in team A.

Now, depending on the order we try to fit the bill, we might end up deducing that we have the right people, or not, unless we start trying different combinations.

For instance, if go down the list and pick Ursula first, we could match her with the "1 doctor" criteria. Then we get to James, and we notice that since he doesn't work in team A, the other criteria about "1 doctor, need to work in team A", can't be filled with him. Since the other two people are nurses, they won't fit that criteria either.

So we backtrack and try James first, and he too can fit the first criteria, and then Ursula can fit the criteria that needs that team.

So the problem looks to us as we need to try different combinations until we've either tried them all, in which case we have some criteria that aren't filled yet, even if the total number of heads working is the same as the total number of heads needed, or we've found a combination that works.

Is this the only solution, can anyone think of a better one?

---

**Edit**: Some clarification.

Comments to this question mentions that with this few people, we should go with brute-force, and I agree, that's probably what we could do, and we might even do that, in the same lane that some sort optimizations look at the size of the data and picks different sort algorithms with less initial overhead if the data size is small.

The problem though is that this is part of a roster planning system, in which you might have quite a few number of people involved, both as "We need X people on the day shift" as well as "We have this pool of Y people that will be doing it", as well as potential for a large "We have this list of Z criteria for those X people that will have to somehow match up with these Y people", and then you add to the fact that we will have a number of days to do the same calculation for, in real-time, as the leader adjusts the roster, and then the need for a speedy solution has come up.

Basically, the leader will see a live sum information on-screen that says how many people are still missing, both on the day-shift as a whole, as well as how many people is fitting the various criteria, and how many people we actually ned in addition to the ones we have. This display will have to update semi-live while the leader adjusts the roster with "What if James takes the day-shift instead of Ursula, and Ursula takes the night-shift".

But huge thanks to the people that has answered this so far, the constraint satisfaction problem sounds like the way we need to go, but we'll definitely look hard at all the links and algorithm names here.

This is why I love StackOverflow :)

Comment: With numbers like 4 and 2, I don't see why *not* to use the simplest-possible brute-force search.

Comment: I agree you should just brute force it if it will always be small. If not, you need to use a heuristic. My guess is it is a variation of the Knapsack problem. I don't know why that answer was removed from this question.

Comment: I agree, I'll edit the question, but I think the answers given already will give us some way to get a head-start on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have there is a [constraint satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem); their relationship to NP is interesting, because they're typically NP but often not NP-complete, i.e. they're tractable to polynomial-time solutions.

As ebo noted in comments, your situation sounds like it can be formulated as an [exact cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), which you can apply [Knuth's Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X) to.  If you take this tack, please let us know how it works out for you.

Comment: If you rewrite the problem to an exact cover problem, you can use Knuth's Algorithm X (or Dancing Links) to solve it. It is a lot faster than trivial backtracking and there are a lot examples on the net.

Comment: @ebo: Sounds more fruitful than anything I was coming up with.  I'm going to incorporate it into my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer--I see nothing in his problem definition that says these criteria are exactly.

Comment: We'll definitely look at all these solutions. Since there are multiple of you that mention the "constraint satisfaction problem", and this is the highest voted answer, I'll accept this, but we'll definitely look into the rest of the answers as well.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel: The "exact" does not relate to the constraints. It's only important that all constraints must be met. Read the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3):

It does look like you have a [constraint satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem).

In your case I would particularly look at constraint propagation techniques first -- you may be able to reduce the problem to a manageable size that way.

What happens if no one fits the criteria?

Comment: Thanks, this definitely sounds like what we need!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the 'Roommate Problem' it is lightly described in [this thesis](http://www.cs.earlham.edu/~uptongl/project/senior_thesis.html).

Bear with me, I'm searching for better links.

**EDIT**

Here's another fairly dense [thesis](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~villars/papers/esa07.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

As for me I would most likely trying to find reduction to [bipartite graph matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching) problem. Also to prove that problem is NP usually is much more complicated than staying you cannot find polynomial solution.

Comment: This is above my level of knowledge for this type of graph, but I'll read up on it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure your problem is NP, it does not smell that way, but what I would do if I was you would be to order the requirements for the positions such that you try to fill the most specific first since fewer people will be available fill these positions, so you are less likely to have to backtrack a lot. There is no reason why you should not combine this with algorithm X, an algorithm of pure Knuth-ness.

Comment: I agree, this is what we originally envisioned as well, but the problem is that the requirement for a "team A association" is only one of 3, which may or may not occur in combination, ie. "team A, and be competent with fire extinguishers, as well as being a nurse", and those 3 types can occur by themselves, or together, which means that in some cases, there's no way to weight one more specific than another.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the theory to others, since my mathematical savvy is not so great, but you may find a tool like Cassowary/Cassowary.net or NSolver useful to represent your problem declaratively as a constraint satisfaction problem and then solve the constraints.

In such tools, the simplex method combined with constraint propagation is frequently employed to deterministically reduce the solution space and then find an optimal solution given a cost function. For larger solution spaces (which don't seem to apply in the size of problem you specify), occasionally genetic algorithms are employed.

If I remember correctly, NSolver also includes in sample code a simplification of an actual Nurse-rostering problem that Dr. Chun worked on in Hong Kong. And there's [a paper on the work he did.](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/IAAI/2000/IAAI00-003.pdf)

Comment: Ooh, nice, tools and software to boot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have a couple of separable problems that would be a lot easier to solve:

-- select one doctor from team A
-- select another doctor from any team
-- select two nurses

So you have three independent problems.

A clarification though, do you have to have two doctors (one from the specified team) and two nurses, or one doctor from the specified team, two nurses, and one other that can be either doctor or nurse?

Comment: The latter, can be any type of employee in fact, otherwise there would be a requirement. It's not really that open though because the person that tries to map people to shifts here has a fixed pool of employees working for him/her, which means that typically there will be a rather homogenous type of employee (ie. mostly doctors, or nurses, or medical staff, or ...). You will typically not have gardeners, janitors, medical staff and road workers in the same pool.

Answer (score 1):

Some Questions:

1. Is the goal to satisfy the constraints *exactly*, or only *approximately* (but as much as possible)?
2. Can a person be a member of several teams?
3. What are all possible constraints? (For example, could we need a doctor which is a member of several teams?)

If you want to satisfy the constraints *exactly*, then I would order the constraints decreasingly by strictness, that is, the ones which are most hardest to achieve (e.g. doctor AND team A in your example above) should be checked **first**!

If you want to satisfy the constraints *approximately*, then its a different story... you would have to specify some kind of weighting/importance-function which determines what we rather would have, when we can't match exactly, and have several possibilities to choose from.

Comment: One person can only be part of a single team, and have a single position in the company in that context, but the last criteria, which stores information about what the person is certified to do (ie. has attended and passed a class in containing a fire, or using CPR, or ...), the person can have multiple of those. The purpose of the system is to try to fill a duty roster that says "We need at least 2 doctors on the day shift, and at least one of those needs to have a certification to use the X-ray machine", etc.

Comment: Sorry for repeating myself, but the case when there is no way to satisfy the constraints, and we have to find some compromise, is this case of interest? Does it occur often? (I don't know that much about hospitals...) :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have several or many constraints, take a look at [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner#EmployeeShiftRostering) (open source, java).

*Brute force*, *branch and bound* and similar techniques take to long. Deterministic algorithms such as *fill the largest shifts first* are very suboptimal. Meta-heuristics are a very good way to deal with this.

Take a specific look at the real-world nurse rostering example of Drools Planner. It's easy to add many constraints, such as "young nurses don't want to work the Saturday night" or "some nurses don't want to work to many days in a row".